# How do I access Java resources in a Grails project?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, intellij-idea

Grails newbie here. My application is in Grails, my IDE is IntelliJ IDEA. I configured my project (in IntelliJ) to say that my resources folder is under `root\src\resources`. I have an image file in there that I need to load into an InputStream / BufferedImage. However I can't seem to get to those resources from my Grails controller. This is what I was trying:

```
def image = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("image.png")
```

But that just returns `null`. I use this exact same convention in Java projects (well, except I have to declare image being of type InputStream), and it does work there. I was under the impression that I could essentially drop Java code in a Grails project and it should just work. What do I need to do differently to get this to work in my Grails controller? I need to access that static resource file.

Answer (score 2):

If you mark a directory as a source directory in IntelliJ IDEA, Grails won't know about it. You have to configure Grails properly by either adding your new directory as a source directory or move the resource to one of the standard source directories.

I've never actually added a new source directory myself, but the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942263/how-to-add-source-folder-to-grails-application) stackoverflow question looks promising.

Other than that, you can just add resources to any source directory and it will be included, for example: `grails-app/conf`, `src/java`, `src/groovy` and more. In addition, any file in `web-app/META-INF/classes` will also be in the classpath of the application. The last one is great to know about if you need to copy a java or groovy source file (i.e. just copy, no compilation).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/resources/yourfile")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this but it's still coming back `null`