# Grails: Unable to import classes from wsdl2java

Tags: java, grails, wsdl, wsdl2java

I'm new to Grails, and I have a problem importing some classes from an external wsdl .
I used wsdl2java to create a class called MacroArgument

```
package xxxx.MacroArgument;
public class MacroArgument {
...
@XmlElement(name = "MacroArgument")
protected String macroArg;
@XmlElement(name = "ID", required = true, type = String.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "long")
protected Long myParamOverrideID;
....getters/setters...
}
```

I created a new domain called TestDomainMacro

```
package it.xxx
import xxxx.MacroArgument;

class TestDomain {
MacroArgument testMacro
static constraints = {
}

}
```

In eclipse I don't have any problem, while running the application with the command "grails run-app" I have this error:

```
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
C:\..pathtofile..\TestDomain.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class xxxx.MacroArgument 
@ line 3, column 1.
import xxxx.MacroArgument;
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve my problem?

Comment: if your code example here is complete, then you lack the package in `MacroArgument` (should be `package xxxx?`).  Otherwise all the regular groovy-finds-nothing rules apply: check the directory structure matching the package, check the classname mathing the filename.  An IDE will most likely help here.

Comment: I edited my question with the package of the generated class as you suggest and I checked in my IDE (Eclipse) that all the resources are correctly linked (the import process in my TestDomain is automatically generated when I define the variable). I hope that my explanation helps.

Comment: where have you put this generated file?  will it end up compiled under `target`?

Comment: sure, target/generated-classes/..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by inserting my class MacroArgument in an external library and then adding the library to the project. Then I imported the class extending a domain of my Grails application.

Answer (score 0):

In which folder is your compiled MacroArgument in Eclipse? 
Is it an addition folder? Maybe grails doesn't know about it?
Try to add this folder to grails configuration.

Look into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942263/how-to-add-source-folder-to-grails-application)

How does you configure your classpath in Eclipse? Check your output in buildconfig.groovy.

grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"

Maybe grails doesn't know about target/generated-classes/ ?
Just try to compile it in target/classes

Comment: I tried also this solution before writing here, I solved my own question by creating an external library with the target generated classes as reported in my own answer.